# Select from bottom of one column to bottom of another in vba

Tags: vba, excel

So I am trying to select from the bottom of one column to the row where another column ends in excel using vba.  I have come up with this and it seems to work but it selects both columns.  How would I write it so that only column B is selected? I am rather new to vba so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sheet7.Range(Range("b1").End(xlDown), Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Select
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Sheet7.Range(Range("b1").End(xlDown), Cells(Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row,"B")).Select`

Comment: Thanks! It works! I just have one more question.  How would I apply this to a larger range than just column b? Like columns b through ai for example.

Comment: You mean selecting the range from the bottom of every preceding column?

Comment: Yes thats what I mean.